# Error 400: Invalid prompt for Google Calendar API PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the codes from Google documentation. [Link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php)

My codes are like this,

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
```

But when I run this, it's giving an error.

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for prompt: Invalid prompt: select_account consent/calendar
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the source code for the library[client.php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/89b3b8c28cdaa709950995f375539429c064d2e5/src/Google/Client.php#L642)

```
   /**
   * Set the prompt hint. Valid values are none, consent and select_account.
   * If no value is specified and the user has not previously authorized
   * access, then the user is shown a consent screen.
   * @param $prompt string
   */
  public function setPrompt($prompt)
  {
    $this->config['prompt'] = $prompt;
  }
```

I dont think you can have both i think you should be setting it to one or the other

```
$client->setPrompt('consent');
```

which would imply that there is a bug in the tutorial you are following.

**My code**

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());
```

my code [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)  and [oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

Comment: Dear @DalmTo, Thanks for your suggestion. 
I've checked with both '**select_account**' and '**consent**'.
But everyone gives error.

When I used '**select_account**', it's giving 
`Invalid parameter value for prompt: Invalid prompt: select_account/calendar`

When '**consent**',
`Invalid parameter value for prompt: Invalid prompt: consent/calendar`

Comment: What happens if you remove that line totally?

Comment: It's giving `Invalid parameter value for approval_prompt: 'auto/calendar' is not valid`

Comment: AS you can see i dont use the prompt

Comment: I'm getting this now `Invalid parameter value for include_granted_scopes: Invalid value, must be one of false, true: true/calendar` :(

Comment: I have no idea where you are getting theses values from you cant just put stuff in the need to be valid.